# oracle formatting ==> to_char(12.222,'000000000009') gives me output as 000000000012. How can I get same format in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
oracle formatting ==>
```

select to_char(12.222,'000000000009') from dual gives me output as 000000000012.

select to_char(1,'000000000009') from dual gives me output as  000000000001.

select to_char(12,'000000000009') from dual gives me output as  000000000012.

How can I get same format in TSQL?

Let me try to elaborate more. I want the number to be formatted in TSQL as it formats in Oracle. Say, if I enter 1 oracle query appends 11 zeros before 1. If i enter 12.22 then oracle query appends 10 zeros before 12.(Note that decimals are not considered)
    similarly if i enter 123 then output will be 9 zeros appended before 123.

Comment: Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
DECLARE @i int=12
DECLARE @digit_number int =10
SELECT REPLICATE('0', @digit_number-LEN(cast(@i as varchar(50))))+cast(@i as varchar(50))
```